# Advice in career path

Tags: machine-learning, data, mathematics, career, programming

I'm currently in Argentina without any type of degree and knowledge in the field of data, maths, programming. My career goal is to get a starting job from here (Argentina) and eventually with some experience, get a data scientist job in Canada. After years and years of gaining a lot of experience in the field of data. I would love to start my own business (there). All that sounds great but right now I have a big. As I said before I don't have any degree or knowledge in anything. What is the best career path (considering my current situation and career goal)? Should I start by pursuing a data science degree or maybe you recommend me to focus in bootcamps/courses/projects/portfolio related to data science?

Comment: Hi @Santiago, welcome to the site. I am afraid here we focus more on technical questions rather than career advice, which is opinion-based. I think your question might be a better fit at other sites like reddit. Actually, [there is already a ton of ML career advice](https://www.google.com/search?q=reddit+machine+learning+career+advice) questions at [r/MachineLearning](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/) that you should check out.

Comment: If you swapped out data science for medicine or law in your question, what would you think to do?